# How to uninstall Android Studio if it is not visible in control panel and also uninstaller is not in the file location

Tags: android-studio, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall Android Studio from Windows 10. But it is not listed in the control panel and also there is no uninstaller file. I tried one way by using **regedit** and going to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` there was Android Studio I deleted that file but still, there is an icon on the Desktop and after clicking it opens the Android Studio. Can anyone tell me what to do now?

Comment: May be you can try to install Android Stuido one more time, then it appear and you can delete it from Add or Remove.

Answer (score 9):

Since you have already removed the entry from **regedit**, now you can easily get rid of the desktop shortcut and the files in the **Android Studio** folder (It is your Android Studio installation folder).

#### Remove Android Studio Files

To remove any remaining Android Studio settings files, open File Explorer and navigate to your user folder (`%USERPROFILE%`), then delete `.android`, `.AndroidStudio`, and any comparable folders with versions at the end, such as `.AndroidStudio1.2`, as well as `.gradle` and `.m2` if they exist.

After that, go to `%APPDATA%` and remove the `JetBrains` directory.

Finally, remove the `Android` directory from `C://Program Files`.

#### Remove SDK

You might also want to remove Android SDK. For that go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%` and delete the `Android` directory.

Answer (score 4):

I guess if you are using Windows,You can go to `C:\Program Files` folder and then you will find android studio(if installed).From there you can delete the folder.This will uninstall android studio.If you do not see it, it is not installed.

OR

if nothing works, install it again and then uninstall it.

P.S. I don't recommend uninstalling programs by just deleting their folders, it's better to use `uninstall.exe` if it exists

Answer (score 2):

If you are using windows 10,

Right-click on the android studio on the taskbar it will open three options right-click again on the top option Android Studio click **properties** select **shortcut tab** in that check **Target** something like this "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe" deletes that folder and then goto users\AppData\Local\andoid delete that folder.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Uninstall Command Displayed in the Registry

Use Registry Editor (Regedit.exe):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

you can get the Android Studio path to Uninstall.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to uninstall studio.
Currently AS doesn't have an uninstall.exe file with it for reasons I don't know. So, I downloaded a previous version of AS as a zip file and then unzipped it.
In the first folder of that, I found uninstall.exe. I copied it to the exact same folder in the current AS and then just double-clicked it. This uninstalled AS but the SDK and others remained.
Then I had to manually go and delete individual folders.

Link from where I downloaded older AS: [AS archive](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)

Answer (score -2):

Search add or remove programs in the windows search bar there you'll get the option to uninstall any programs from your PC

Comment: There also I could not find this program.

Comment: look for the program in the control panel, you can uninstall it from there